# Is there a "post-startup" hook in Azure Functions?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I need to execute a function after the configuration and dependency injection has finished when the function app is loaded. Is there something similar to `FunctionsStartup` or a function trigger to achieve this?

The code I need to run relies on the database context so I can't use that without introducing circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There are no pre or post invocations available for Azure Functions. It would violate the serverless design. Function invocations are meant to be independent from each other, so there is no way to guarantee that some code is executed only once.

Circular dependencies can be avoided by carefully designing the Azure Function references. We can think of implementing stateful functions using Durable Functions.

You can check this [durable function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) for more information.

To initialize the dependencies, you can also check this [Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) document.